# Ошибка при загрузке нескольких файлов TLSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, telegram, tlsharp

Мне нужно отправлять одному пользователю файлы по запросу. Я использую TLSharp. Сделал небольшой сервис ASP.NET Core Web API, где по HTTP запросу отправляю файл пользователю.

Все хорошо работает, когда отправляю один файл, но если приходит 2 и более запросов с небольшим промежутком, то происходит ошибка `System.InvalidOperationException: invalid checksum! skip`.

Контроллер:

```cs
[Route("upload/{driveId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(string driveId)
{
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var file = service.Files.Get(driveId);
            string filename = file.Execute().Name;
            await file.DownloadAsync(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(filename, out var mime);

            var stream = new StreamReader(ms, true);
            await _client.SendFileToBot(filename, mime, stream, driveId);

            return Ok();
}
```

**SendFileToBot**:

```cs
public async Task SendFileToBot(string filename, string mime, StreamReader stream)
{
            var found = await client.SearchUserAsync("username", 1);

            //find user
            var userToSend = found.Users
                .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TLUser))
                .Cast<TLUser>()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1234567);

            var fileResult = await client.UploadFile(filename, stream);
            var attr = new TLVector<TLAbsDocumentAttribute>()
            {
                new TLDocumentAttributeFilename { FileName = filename }
            };
            var bot = new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = userToSend.Id, AccessHash = userToSend.AccessHash.Value };
            await client.SendUploadedDocument(bot, fileResult, "caption", mime, attr);
}
```

Я знаю, что эта ошибка происходит, из-за того что запросы отпрвляются с небольшим промежутком и TLSharp отправляет их на сервер Telegram одним пакетом.

**Как это можно исправить?** Я пробовал использовать Task.Delay и пытался обрабатывать кадлый запрос в отдельном треде, но у меня не получилось.

Comment: А стектрейс покажите, даже лучше прямо exception.Tostring().

Comment: Я думаю стоит дождаться ответа и после отправлять следующий пакет

Comment: @VdovinDaniil есть пример, как можно это сделать?

Comment: @Nikita Создайте слушатель который будет проверять свободен поток или нет. К сожалению более подробно описать процесс создания не могу.

Comment: @Nikita я решал подобную проблему но делал это на стороне сервера.

Comment: интересно как какой строке выбивает exception

Answer (score 1):

1. Насколько я вижу проблема в StreamReader stream который вы передаете в метод
2. я не вижу чтобы этот stream закрывался где то
3. Тоже самое с MemoryStream

### Вариант 1 закрыть поток

```
public async Task SendFileToBot(string filename, string mime, StreamReader stream)
{
            var found = await client.SearchUserAsync("username", 1);

            //find user
            var userToSend = found.Users
                .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TLUser))
                .Cast<TLUser>()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1234567);

            var fileResult = await client.UploadFile(filename, stream);
            stream.Close();//Закрыть поток после того как он не нужен 

            var attr = new TLVector<TLAbsDocumentAttribute>()
            {
                new TLDocumentAttributeFilename { FileName = filename }
            };
            var bot = new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = userToSend.Id, AccessHash = userToSend.AccessHash.Value };
            await client.SendUploadedDocument(bot, fileResult, "caption", mime, attr);
}
```

### Вариант 2 использовать мутекс

> private static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(); **ОН статичный вызывать через класс**

```
[Route("upload/{driveId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(string driveId)
    {
        mutex.WaitOne();
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var file = service.Files.Get(driveId);
        string filename = file.Execute().Name;
        await file.DownloadAsync(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(filename, out var mime);

        var stream = new StreamReader(ms, true);
        await _client.SendFileToBot(filename, mime, stream, driveId);
        ms.Close();
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        return Ok();
    }

 public async Task SendFileToBot(string filename, string mime, StreamReader stream)
    {
        var found = await client.SearchUserAsync("username", 1);

        //find user
        var userToSend = found.Users
            .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TLUser))
            .Cast<TLUser>()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1234567);

        var fileResult = await client.UploadFile(filename, stream);
        stream.Close();

        var attr = new TLVector<TLAbsDocumentAttribute>()
        {
            new TLDocumentAttributeFilename { FileName = filename }
        };
        var bot = new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = userToSend.Id, AccessHash = userToSend.AccessHash.Value };
        await client.SendUploadedDocument(bot, fileResult, "caption", mime, attr);
    }
```

### Вариант 3 вызывать синхронно

```
[Route("upload/{driveId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(string driveId)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var file = service.Files.Get(driveId);
        string filename = file.Execute().Name;
        await file.DownloadAsync(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(filename, out var mime);

        var stream = new StreamReader(ms, true);
        var found = await client.SearchUserAsync("username", 1);

        //find user
        var userToSend = found.Users
            .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TLUser))
            .Cast<TLUser>()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1234567);

        var fileResult = await client.UploadFile(filename, stream);
        stream.Close();
        ms.Close();
        var attr = new TLVector<TLAbsDocumentAttribute>()
        {
            new TLDocumentAttributeFilename { FileName = filename }
        };
        var bot = new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = userToSend.Id, AccessHash = userToSend.AccessHash.Value };
        await client.SendUploadedDocument(bot, fileResult, "caption", mime, attr);

        return Ok();
    }
```